# Shell script convert jpg images

Tags: shell-script

*Edited as I changed some things 
I'm currently working on a code, where a shell script searches a specific folder from the user input for jpg images.  It should then sort them by date and convert them to a single picture.
Here is my current code:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.jpg -printf | sort -t | 
convert @- -append "${filename%.*}.jpg"
```

I have put it in a for loop. If I would like to rename it the the complete input, where could I add that to the code?

Comment: You mentioned a shell script. Can you explain how you run this script, for example do you have the script , we'll call it myscript.sh, and do you have it somehow in your $PATH so that you manually go to the folder of interest, run `myscript.sh` and it does the work?

Comment: Is there a reason you [deleted the content of your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/233892/2)?

Answer (score 3):

Just change `.` to `"${1-.}"`. `$1` is the first argument passed to the script, you can also default to `.` if no argument is passed as I've done here (by using "`-`", which sets a default value if the variable is unset).

Also note that your script is liable to break if any filenames contain newlines. If that matters to you, consider using `find ... -print0` and `sort -0`.